# Do I need to report income to the US if working from home from Canada for a US company?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, international

If I worked for an American company *at home from Canada* (I'm a Canadian citizen), do I need to report income / pay taxes to the US, because the company is from the US? I'm specifically asking about an oDesk job, working at home for a US company. Does the answer differ depending on whether it is an hourly job or a fixed-rate job?

Answer (score 3):

No, if you are not present in the US - you do not need to report anything. It may be though that your payer will have to withhold amounts for the IRS on your behalf, and you'll have to submit a non-resident tax return to claim refunds.

Comment: Okay, I would not be working in the US. However, I would be storing my work on US servers (i.e. mail, Google Drive, Dropbox, Cloud9). Am I still exempt from tax reporting?

Comment: How on earth do you know where the services are? Why would you care? I cannot understand what's the connection

Comment: I just wanted to confirm :). My thought was that because my work is technically in the US and I didn't want any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "it depends".

If taxes were withheld, you may need to file a return.

This might help:
http://taxes.about.com/od/taxplanning/qt/form_W8BEN.htm

Comment: The question was whether he needs to report income or pay taxes, not whether he needs to file a return. If taxes were withheld he doesn't *need* to file a return. He *should*, but doesn't have to.